# SQL comint history saves spaces are \40

Tags: comint, sql-mode

When accessing a database through an inferior process (`M-x sql-msql`) the history for the current session history (M-p/n) works Ok. But when restoring history entries from a previous session the string '\40' is found where spaces are supposed to be. ej. `select\40username\40from\40users;`.

I'm guessing the issue is related to 40 being 32, the ascii value of space, in octal. But I can't figure out where things go south. Any idea or how to fix this or what could be causing this behaviour?